# XMLHttpRequest и Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: vue.js, xmlhttprequest

Интересно стало написать биржу криптовалюты ( визуально ). Использую Vue.js и Axois.js.
Выдаёт ошибку:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://kenanprod.ru' is therefore not allowed access.`
Сайт: `https://kenanprod.ru/crypto/crypto.html`
Код:

```js
let CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_URI = "https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist";
let COINMARKETCAP_API_URI = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com";
let UPDATE_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    coins: [],
    coinData: {}
  },
  methods: {
    getCoinData: function() {
      let self = this;

      axios.get(CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_URI)
        .then((resp) => {
          this.coinData = resp.data.Data;
          this.getCoins();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.getCoins();
          console.error(err);
        });
    },
    getCoins: function() {
      let self = this;

      axios.get(COINMARKETCAP_API_URI + "/v1/ticker/?limit=10")
        .then((resp) => {
          this.coins = resp.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    },
    getCoinImage: function(symbol) {
      symbol = (symbol === "MIOTA" ? "IOT" : symbol);
      symbol = (symbol === "VERI" ? "VRM" : symbol);

      return CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_URI + this.coinData[symbol].ImageUrl;
    },
    getColor: (num) => {
      return num > 0 ? "color:green;" : "color:red;";
    },
  },
  created: function () {
    this.getCoinData();
  }
});
setInterval(() => {
  app.getCoins();
}, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

```html
    <div id="app">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Rank</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Symbol</td>
            <td>Price (USD)</td>
            <td>1H</td>
            <td>1D</td>
            <td>1W</td>
            <td>Market Cap (USD)</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-cloak v-for="coin in coins">
            <td>{{ coin.rank }}</td>
            <td><img v-bind:src="getCoinImage(coin.symbol)"> {{ coin.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ coin.symbol }}</td>
            <td>{{ coin.price_usd | currency }}</td>
            <td v-bind:style="getColor(coin.percent_change_1h)">
              <span v-if="coin.percent_change_1h > 0">+</span>{{ coin.percent_change_1h }}%
            </td>
            <td v-bind:style="getColor(coin.percent_change_24h)">
              <span v-if="coin.percent_change_24h > 0">+</span>{{ coin.percent_change_24h }}%
            </td>
            <td v-bind:style="getColor(coin.percent_change_7d)">
              <span v-if="coin.percent_change_7d > 0">+</span>{{ coin.percent_change_7d }}%
            </td>
            <td>{{ coin.market_cap_usd | currency }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: почитай... https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать переадресацию на php файл